# carousel image with fixed ratio & min width

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to create a carousel like https://squareup.com/. I want the image to have a fixed ratio, a minimum width and handle up to 1400px width screen. Everything I try with CSS breaks.

CSS:

```
.carousel .item {
  height: 800px;
}
.carousel img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 1400px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Is there a responsive plugin or image slider I could use? Or a CSS trick I'm woefully unaware of.

Comment: If you're looking for a plugin, Bootstrap has a carousel: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel.

Comment: I'm using the bootstrap carousel already. The problem is how it works is not producing the outcome I want. I can't get that carousel to act like the square page with regard to the img ratio, min width, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter carousel is responsive out-of-the-box. First of all, change `min-width: 1400px;` to `max-width: 1400px;` if you want to screens **up to** 1400px.

But, you won`t get fixed ratio (and there is no fixed ratio at your example). For this, you may use CSS3 media queries to change width and height of the picture.